# Is it possible to create a copy of a Docker container in its current state while its running a command?

Tags: docker

I have a docker container that runs an interactive program similar to IPython in that it reads from STDIN and prints to STDOUT and whatnot. As such, this container is virtually always run in interactive mode. Is it possible to clone the docker container while it is running this program such that the state of the image is exactly the same (e.g. if the user typed in `x=5` an hour ago the cloned container will already be running IPython with all of that history preserved)? I suppose this is similar to "saving the machine state" in VirtualBox.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible until you preserve data... as the system variables are in heap. You cannot regain its values.

Once we create new container..it runs as a new process and it has it's own storage.